# How do I write a sort function without using loops?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive sort function with no loops at all.

```
void insertionSortRecursive(int arr[], int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return;

    insertionSortRecursive( arr, n-1 );

    int last = arr[n-1];
    int j = n-2;


    while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > last)
    {
        arr[j+1] = arr[j];
        j--;
    }
    arr[j+1] = last;
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of while loop and still make this function work?

Comment: Why don't you create a second function ? By the way, a merge loop is more easy to write in recursive.

Comment: While you *could* write it without loops, it's not a good idea to do so.

Comment: There's no practical reason to eliminate the loop. Indeed, for most practical purposes, you want to eliminate recursion
!

Comment: This has got to be a school assignment @RaymondChen. Nobody tells a dev to eliminate loops in favor of recursion otherwise

Comment: Well, yes, it's surely a homework.dump.  All these 'drive a nail without using a hammer' questions are of next-to-no use to future SO users:(

Comment: Well, in that case, the OP had better cite this web site as a source when they turn in their assignment, so they are not guilty of plagiarism. (SO is for solving practical problems, and converting loops to recursion is very impractical. In particular, it increases memory requirements from O(1) to O(n) or possibly O(n^2) which is pretty awful.)

Comment: Just use the standard sort function. There's no practical reason to write your own sort function. `int compare(void* a, void* b) { int first = *(int*)a, second = *(int*)b; return first < second ? -1 : first == second ? 0 : 1; } void no_loop_sort(int arr[], int n) { qsort(arr, n, sizeof(int), compare); }`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code which comes in [here](http://analgorithmaday.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/insertion-sortrecursive-method.html) (remove the `while` using another recursive function):

```
void insertInOrder( int element,int *a, int first, int last)
{
    if (element >= a[last])
        a[last+1] = element;
    else if (first < last)
    {
        a[last+1] = a[last];
        insertInOrder(element, a, first, last-1);
    }
    else // first == last and element < a[last]
    {
        a[last+1] = a[last];
        a[last] = element;
    }
}
void insertion_sort_recur(int *arr, int first, int last)
{
    if(first < last)
    {
        insertion_sort_recur(arr, first, last-1); // avoids looping thru arr[0..last-1]
        insertInOrder(arr[last], arr, first, last-1); // considers arr[last] as the first element in the unsorted list
    }
}   
void main()
{
    int A[]={5,3,2,4,6,1};
    insertion_sort_recur(A,0,5);
}
```